# Check_box problems to retrieve the one checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use this form to put checkboxes on a form:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
<input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
</label>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I try to get the checkboxes checked with my parameters, I always can get only one (the last one checked, example: if I check 1 and 2, I will get 2 only).

How can I do to get them in my controller?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving your inputs a name attribute with unique value attributes and unique id attributes.

Example:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
<input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="first" value="1" name="box-selections[]" checked> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="second" value="2" name="box-selections[]"> Checkbox 2
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="third" value="3" name="box-selections[]"> Checkbox 3
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, it worked, my problem was that the name I was putting did not have [] at the end ! Thanks a lot Nitsew !